# How to read property of Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am selecting value from Drop down and want to use it in following way.
Like here I am returning value from drop down in variable selectedtext.

```js
  <p style="font-size:150%;margin-left:20%; margin-top:50px"> Sources :
        <select id="drop" name="drop">
            <option value="0">Select Source</option>
            <option value="1">RBSK</option>
            <option value="2">MIDRS</option>
            <option value="3">ATM </option>
            <option value="4">RT </option>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#drop").change(function () {
       var  selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
//var selectedValue = $(this).val();
//alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Now I want to use this value here:

```js
var deMapping = {
            RBSK: {'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
                {
                    xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
                    dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
                    categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
                }
                ]},
           ATM:{},
           ABC:{},
           DEF:{}
};
```

I want to use selectedText in this way:

```
deMapping.RBSK.des[5].categoryOptionCombo; //Here it will return the correct value of 6th element in des array.
```

Now I want to replace the RBSK with selectedText which user selects from dropdown.

So if User selects ATM it should return values related with ATM. Like   `deMapping.selectedText.des[5].categoryOptionCombo;` becomes  `deMapping.ATM.des[5].categoryOptionCombo;` if user selects ATM from dropdown

Can anybody help?

Comment: use deMapping[selectedText].des[5].categoryOptionCombo

Comment: Why do you need `des` as an array ? You already have  different `object` for different selected value

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I had tried what I understand.

`deMapping.RBSK.des[5].categoryOptionCombo;` //Here it will return the correct value of 6th element in des array.

For `des` there is not six object so that will not work.

Here the working snippet for replacing but it only works for option RBSK because other options don't have any data.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-size:150%;margin-left:20%; margin-top:50px"> Sources :
<select id="drop" name="drop">
    <option value="0">Select Source</option>
    <option value="RBSK">RBSK</option>
    <option value="MIDRS">MIDRS</option>
    <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
    <option value="RT">RT</option>
</select>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var deMapping = {
    RBSK: {'dsUID': 'tdTwLUxcQ8R', rootNodeName: 'RBSK_GIS_Indicator', orgUnitTagName: 'MCTSCode', des: [
    {
        xmlid: "Childhood_Diseases_0_6_Female",
        dataElement: "oV163sbcJ0N",
        categoryOptionCombo: "Cmzbo9LD8pJ"
    }
    ]},
    ATM:{},
    ABC:{},
    DEF:{}
};
$(function () {
    $("#drop").change(function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        alert(deMapping[selectedText].des[0].categoryOptionCombo);
    });
});
</script>
```